# JW Player smarty not working

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, jwplayer, clipbucket

I have clipbucket installed with their custom JWPlayer. But its old and i am upgrading to pro. 
Now for i have changed the player and standard videos are working correctly without any issues, but i can not add toggel HD video in code. If anyone please tell me how do i impalement it correctly,

I want to add

```html
sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4",
        label: "720p HD"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4",
        label: "360p SD",
        "default": "true"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo180mp4",
        label: "180p Web"
      }]
```

Into following player code

```html
<div id="mediaplayer">Loading player, please wait....</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cb_player_file = '{$cb_player_url}/player.swf';
var cb_player_url = '{$cb_player_url}';
var player_logo = '{$player_logo}';
var hq_video_file = '{$hq_vid_file}';
var normal_video_file = '{$normal_vid_file}';
var ytcode = '{$ytcode}';
var pre_item = "";
var next_item = "";
var preview_img = '{getThumb vdetails=$vdata size="big"}';
var embed_type = '{$Cbucket->configs.embed_type}';

jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({ldelim}
  {if $ytcode}
  file: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={$ytcode}',
  {else}
  file: normal_video_file,
  {/if}
  image: preview_img,
  width: '{$player_data.width}',
  height:'{$player_data.height}',
  autostart : '{$player_data.autoplay}',
  primary :"flash",
  startparam: "start",
  'logo':{ldelim}
   file :player_logo ,
   link :baseurl,
   margin : '{$logo_margin}',
   position : '{$logo_placement}',
   timeout : '3',
   over :'1',
   out :'0.5'
  {rdelim},
 {rdelim});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Clip-Bucket before, but I know that when using JW6, you need to set the player up like this - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
      image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
      sources: [{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo360.mp4"
      },{
        file: "/uploads/myVideo720mp4"
      }]
    });
</script>
```